# Designing related query for implementing a Restful application in Spring 3

Tags: spring-3, restful-architecture

I already have an application implemented in Spring MVC 3.0. Now i want to convert this application into a restful application in such a way that bussiness logic remains in one application and web layer remains in another application.

Now to achieve this using Rest my web layer will act as a rest client which will access the services exposed by the business logic implementation related application

The point where i am confused is how should i implement login for this.

Should i send the login credentials from the web application to the service application in a rest post request and then maintain the id that would act as a jsessionid authorizing my further requests

Or should i authenticate and authorize every request

Or is there any design pattern already proposed by Spring for achieving this kind of requirement.

Can anyone having knowledge about this help me.

Answer (score 0):

You should have auth on both the REST web layer and the 'normal'/client web layer. The easiest way to think about this is to ignore the fact that in your current situation you will be writing both the client and service side of the REST API. Instead, consider the client connections to be coming from an external source.

This should make it clear that the REST service needs to authenticate all requests. Generally, you'll authenticate each request separately with HTTP Basic Auth; if the data is sensitive or the credentials need to be protected for some other reason, you can use SSL. From where you get these credentials is probably application-specific.

It's a common pattern to have an API key of some kind, where the client will authenticate itself with the key but users of the client are not known individually by the API. You could also implement a sort of pass-through auth, where the client user's credentials are sent with each request to the API, so long as your API knows something about these users. In this case, your users could either use the client (your already-implemented webapp) or directly use the API.